# regex101.com expression doesn't work in actual python

Tags: python, regex

I needed a regex to find an exact number of matching digits in a string of digits.  (example, "exactly three repeating-digits")

On [regex101 I got a functioning regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/MEHSgz/2)  `(^|(.)(?!\2))(\d)\3{2}(?!\3)`

but when I try it in a python3.6 shell,  it fails, with `match` returning None:

```
import re
three_char_re  = re.compile("(^|(.)(?!\2))(\d)\3{2}(?!\3)")
print(three_char_re.match("14551114"))
```

Is there some default flag that differs between my python environment and regex101 perhaps?  I cannot find a difference in the regex or the test input.

Comment: So the pattern itself is correct?

Comment: @Thefourthbird i dont think so...but m not sure what OP is looking for

Comment: yes, the expression is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

Use raw strings (see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) for Python regexps. Hint: `”\d”` is not a backslash followed by a “d”. Change it like:

```
three_char_re  = re.compile(r"(^|(.)(?!\2))(\d)\3{2}(?!\3)")
```

Notice that it’s `compile(r”...”)`, not `compile(“...”)`? The short version is that this preserves the backslashes.

Second, Use `three_char_re.search` or `three_char_re.find_all` instead of `.match`, so that you can find matches that aren’t at the start of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
three_char_re  = re.compile(r"(^|(.)(?!\2))(\d)\3{2}(?!\3)")
print(three_char_re.findall("14551114"))
```

Output: `[('5', '5', '1')]`

You need to use `findall` as `match` starts from first character and your regex does not match from first character.

Comment: also my expression didn't have the leading 'r'  (eg. `re.compile(r"(^|(."`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your pattern as a raw string to escape `\` character with prefix `r`.

This following pattern will search for the 3 first successive identical digits

```
import re
result = re.search(r"([0-9])\1\1","14551114")) 
# <re.Match object; span=(4, 7), match='111'>
print(result.group() 
# '111'
```

Comment: yeah, the complexity is that it there must be a case of exactly 3 digits, no more no less.  1222456 True,   1222245 False,  13335660 True, 1333349990 True